# Northwest and SouthEast coordinates of mapView

Tags: android

Hello i m Working On Application That Requires Northwest and Southeast Coordinates of Mapview when i zoom or pan around map...i want to calculate distance between this two Geopoints...

Guide Me Please...

Thanx..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get TopLeft and BottomRight coordinate of screen and project it to geographical coordinates. For this you need to know about size of **MapView**, because if you get 0;0 as TopLeft and screenHeight;screenWidth as BottomRight you will be disappointed. This is because **MapView** do not fill the whole screen of device, because always there is notification panel and in some applications there is title bar. 
So, but if you get height of **MapView** by calling method ***getHeight()***, for example, in ***onCreate*** or **onStart** you will get 0, because **MapView** has not been drawn. You need to inherit from **MapView** and override ***onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)***